# What was the anti-CRC ruling?

Tags: history, chabad, satmar

I understand that, circa 1980, a religious authority for Lubavitch hasidim ruled that foods certified as kosher by the Satmar *His'achadus Harabanim* (CRC) not be eaten.

1. What form did this ruling take? Was it an excommunication on manufacturers who hired the CRC to certify their products? or an halachic ruling that the CRC is unreliable? or what?
2. Did the ruling apply to foods certified by both the CRC and another (otherwise reliable) agency as kosher? (The answer to this question may well be obvious once the preceding question is answered.)
3. Did the ruling apply to other actions taken by the CRC? It's a *bes din*, after all. For example: If the CRC issued a *get* (I don't know whether it has ever issued *gitin*), would this ruling prevent marrying the divorced woman? (The answer to this question, too, may well be obvious once the first question is answered.)

(One thing I'm *not* asking is *why* the ruling was issued. But if you have to include that information in your answer in order to answer the above questions, then by all means.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19123/discussion-between-yishai-and-msh210).

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99021/170

Answer (score 3):

It appears from the [original letter](http://old2.ih.chabad.info/images/notimage/29301_en_1.pdf) of the protest that the ruling assumed the form of an injunction by the Vaad Rabbanei Lubavitch prohibiting upon its adherents the consumption of any products that carried the Satmar Hisachdus HaRabbanim's *hashgachah*. I don't believe it was directed not at manufacturers hiring HH nor an attempt to discredit the latter's reliability. I believe it was a move to damage their business flow. If it was intended to render HH unreliable, then it would follow that any ruling emanating from HH would be invalid, while from the letter's wording it appears that only products carrying this *hashgachah* were under ban, not every ruling that came from Satmar's HH.